# Acceptance rate should have been kept

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

Acceptance rate should have been kept.

Right now there is no way for people to see whether that person accepts answers or not.

I really don't think that this is fair.

Comment: Without this info, you have to judge the question on the merits of the  question alone. Which is **A Good Thing™**!

Comment: I am totally disagree. Anyway this is my opinion. You can give even -100 :D

Comment: Well, you're stating your opinion. You're not asking a question, you're not suggesting a change. You're not arguing your case. What did you expect from this "question"? Also, did you [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)?

Comment: I was in favor of keeping accept rate displayed, but Joachim is right: this is not a good Meta question, so even though I agree with you, I can't upvote.

Answer (score 10):

A golden rule:

#### Don't answer only for the OP. Answer for the community.

If your answer is fine the community will reward you by upvotes. Accepted answer means the OP used that answer for his solution.

Comment: +1 - **`Accepted answer means OP used that answer for his/her solution.`** and not necessarily always means that is the correct answer.

Comment: The flaw in this answer is that it assumes such a community exists.  There are a *large* number of tags in the long tail of SO that have none.  And [android] of course.

Comment: @UphillLuge - (IMHO) But still if I know the answer I ofcourse answer the question keeping in mind that it will help anyone (including not SE users) in future. even if I don't get any vote:)

Answer (score 6):

I can see that you have a 25% accept rate on Meta by looking at your profile and counting. Granted, if you had more than 4 questions getting the exact percentage would take some work, but if you really care if a person tends to accept answers you can say "that's not a lot of green" and take whatever action you would take if you saw a low number displayed.

And hey, if that action you would have taken would be to look at their earlier questions and see if they actually have good answers worth accepting before judging them and deciding not to answer, you're already on the right page to do it.

Comment: Not that you really should for reasons of answering/not answering. Questions should stand on their own merit, no matter who asked. =)

Comment: actually my accept rate is 100% :) I give value to every answerer. That is my pride. People spending time for me and i give value to them.

Comment: +1 - If getting the exact percentage takes some work, then the exact percentage doesn't matter.  Going to the user profile to look around is *greatly* preferable to relying on a single (often misleading) statistic.

Comment: @BillTheLizard I can remember at least once (I think more than once) having to point out the hover text to users making statements like "50 questions and 20% accept rate, you're lame", when only, say, 10 of the questions had answers.  Very misleading indeed.